# What's the minimum number of rows where indexing becomes valuable in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I've read that indexing on some databases (*SQL Server is the one I read about*) doesn't have much effect until you cross a certain threshold of rows because the database will hold the entire table X in memory.

Ordinarily, I'd plan to index on my WHEREs and unique columns/lesser-changed tables. After hearing about the suggested minimum (*which was about 10k*), I wanted to learn more about that idea. If there are tables that I know will never pass a certain point, this might change the way I index some of them.

For something like MySQL MyISAM/INNODB, is there a point where indexing has little value and what are some ways of determining that?

**Note:** Very respectfully, I'm not looking for suggestions about structuring my database like "You should index anyway," I'm looking to understand this concept, if it's true or not, how to determine the thresholds, and similar information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the major uses of indexes is to reduce the number of pages being read.  The index itself is usually smaller than the table.  So, *just in terms of page read/writes*, you generally need at least three data pages to see a benefit, because using an index requires at least two data pages (one for the index and one for the original data).

(Actually, if the index covers the query, then the breakeven is two.)

The number of data pages needed for a table depends on the size of the records and the number of rows.  So, it is really not possible to specify a threshold on the number of rows.

The above very rudimentary explanation leaves out a few things:

- The cost of scanning the data pages to do comparisons for each row.
- The cost of loading and using index pages.
- Other uses of indexing.

But it gives you an idea, and you can see benefits on tables much smaller than 10k rows.  That said you can easily do tests on your data to see how queries work on the tables in question.

Also, I strongly, strongly recommend having primary keys on all tables and using those keys for foreign key relationships.  The primary key itself is an index.

Answer (score 2):

Indexes serve a lot of purposes. InnoDB tables are always organized as an index, on the cluster key. Indexes can be used to enforce unique constraints, as well as support foreign key constraints. The topic of "indexes" spans way more than query performance.

In terms of query performance, it really depends on what the query is doing. If we are selecting a small subset of rows, out of large set, then effective use of an index can speed that up by eliminating vast swaths of rows from being checked. That's where the biggest bang comes from.

If we are pulling all of the rows, or nearly all the rows, from a set, then an index typically doesn't help narrow down which rows to check; even when an index is available, the optimizer may choose to do a full scan of all of the rows.

But even when pulling large subsets, appropriate indexes can improve performance for join operations, and can significantly improve performance of queries with GROUP BY or ORDER BY clauses, by making use of an index to retrieve rows in order, rather than requiring a "Using filesort" operation.

If we are looking for a simple rule of thumb... for a large set, if we are needing to pull (or look at) less than 10% of the total rows, then an access plan using a suitable index will typically outperform a full scan. If we are looking for a specific row, based on a unique identifier, index is going to be faster than full scan. If we are pulling all columns for every row in the table n no particular order, then a full scan is going to be faster.

Again, it really comes down to what operations are being performed. What queries are being executed, and the performance profile that we need from those queries. That is going to be the key to determining the indexing strategy.

In terms of gaining understanding, use `EXPLAIN` to see the execution plan. And learn the operations available to MySQl optimizer.

(The topic of indexing strategy in terms of database performance is much too large for a StackOverflow question.)

Answer (score 0):

Each situation is different. If you profile your code, then you'll understand better each anti-pattern. To demonstrate the extreme unexpectedness, consider Oracle:

If this were Oracle, I would say zero because if an empty table's high water mark is very high, then a query that motivates a full table scan that returns zero rows would be much more expensive than the same query that were to induce even a full index scan.

The same process that I went through to understand Oracle you can do with MySQL: profile your code.